# Update column in a table with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table test

```
id       Name           idREF     FORMULE 
1        A              gR        gR1+gR2+gR3  
2        B              gR1       123  
3        C              gR2       124  
4        e              gR3       125 
11       A1             gR11      gR21-gR31  
12       B1             gR21      1231  
13       C1             gR31      1241
```

How can I modify the table test : replace formule(+ or -) by its value .

So I will get

```
  id       Name           idREF     FORMULE     FORMULERESULT 
  1        A              gR        gR1+gR2+gR3 123+124+125 
  2        B              gR1       123          123  
  3        C              gR2       124          124  
  4        e              gR3       125          125  
  11       A1             gR11      gR21-gR31   1231-1241 
  12       B1             gR21      1231         1231  
  13       C1             gR31      1241         1241
```

Comment: Do you want to use the computed value in column formule. I mean what you need- 372 or 123+124+125

Comment: @ManishGupta I want to get 123+124+125 as string .

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I honestly think this has no place in a relational database

Comment: It would have solution using PARTITION BY and CTE (if using SQL), but as @Phil mentioned, the table structure is messed up.

Comment: @Marek what's wrong with the table structure .I didn't get it .

Comment: @user3548593 I would prefer the way when storing a formula, have a separate column on result it's result, so you don't need to compute again. It is much easier and more efficient, thought - but I might be also wrong!

Comment: @Marek I update my question, any help would be appreciated !

Comment: I didn't get it very well , I am newbie with mysql .

Comment: @PeterLang question updated

Comment: @user3548593 The problem is that your `FORMULE` column is essentially a multi-value column, which SQL has a _really_ hard time with, because it violates one of the fundamental principles for good table design.  There are existing questions here that deal with this general problem, but it's better to avoid it when you can; you can design the system so that this isn't a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CREATE function dbo.converttoMap
(@value varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @result varchar(100)

    select @value = REPLACE(@value, idREF, formule) 
  from fortable where  @value like '%'+idREF+'%' and formule not  LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
  set @result=@value
    return(@result)
END
```

Run this function, Then use this function in update query

```
update ForTable set FORMULE=dbo.converttoplus(FORMULE) where formule LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Use your table name instead of ForTable

Comment: Not quite understand .

Comment: This is nowhere near involved enough to work.  Essentially, you'd have to build a (simple) syntax-parsing tree, which I **really** wouldn't do in vanilla SQL (stored procedure, maybe).